# Select new products by hand on PrestaShop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

PrestaShop v. 1.7.6 shows new products on homepage which are added to shop in last X days. But usually, this doesn't work for my clients, because they want to select them by hand. There are a lot of new products and only a few have to be promoted.

How it is possible to let the client Select which products will be in section "New" on the homepage and these products also should have LABEL "NEW" in categories listing everywhere in the shop, as it is by default for new products in PrestaShop.

Answer (score 2):

`New` products are selected automatically by PrestaShop.

By default, all products you add are considered to be New. You may change number of days during which your products is considered as `New` at

> Shop Parameters -> Product Settings -> Number of days for which the product is considered 'new'

Then the only way to select the products considered as new is modifying the field `date_add` at table `ps_product`.

Answer (score 1):

You can override module ps_newproducts to change the expected behavior.
I did that on one of my project. I have override the module for a manual selection of products to display, it's more simple

Comment: This method would be good if I could edit condition when LABEL "NEW" is still applied on products when in browsing categories... Is this possible?

Comment: You can create category "New product" and display only product from this category too. In any case you must override module

Answer (score 1):

The simple way is to use the ps_featuredproducts module and change translations.

This module works by position and you can change position manually.

Comment: What about adding labels in products list "NEW"? Where can I set them? Thanks!

Comment: @Gediminas you have to modify date_add field manually on the database (ps_product)

Answer (score 0):

I created a new category "News" to select products by hand. So now I need to add label in listing and product page:

/catalog/_partials/miniatiures/product.tpl:

```
  {block name='product_flags'}
    <ul class="product-flags">
      <!-- CUSTOM CODE -->
      {foreach from=Product::getProductCategoriesFull($product.id_product) item=cat}
        {if $cat.name== 'News' }
          <li class="product-flag new">New</li>
        {/if}
      {/foreach}
      <!-- / CUSTOM CODE -->

      {foreach from=$product.flags item=flag}
        <li class="product-flag {$flag.type}">{$flag.label}</li>
      {/foreach}
    </ul>
  {/block}
```

/catalog/product.tpl:

```
      {block name='product_flags'}
        <ul class="product-flags">
          <!-- CUSTOM CODE -->
          {foreach from=Product::getProductCategoriesFull(Tools::getValue('id_product')) item=cat}
            {if $cat.name== 'News' }
              <li class="product-flag new">New</li>
            {/if}
          {/foreach}
          <!-- / CUSTOM CODE -->
          {foreach from=$product.flags item=flag}
            <li class="product-flag {$flag.type}">{$flag.label}</li>
          {/foreach}
        </ul>
      {/block}
```

To show these products in homepage I have used this FREE MODULE:
https://mypresta.eu/modules/front-office-features/featured-products.html